# How do I refactor nodejs Buffer usage into pure JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring, buffer

I don't have nodejs available to use, and I can't install it in this project.  The example I am provided is written in Node JS and is as follows:

Edit: Assume all of the parameters are just strings. No objects

`var value = Buffer.from(apiKey + integerstring + timestamp + '1').toString('base64');`

I need to have this without the `Buffer.from` but since I do not know node, and I am having trouble reverse engineering the buffer source code, I am asking SO for a quick solution.

Comment: [Buffer for the browser](https://github.com/feross/buffer)

Comment: `btoa(apiKey + integerstring + timestamp + '1')` ? assuming all the *variables* are strings of course